# Create an unique ID for multiple rows SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have a number of user ID's. I am inserting these into a group table which will contain a column for the user's ID and the group ID. This will allow me to use the query "SELECT user_id FROM groups WHERE group_id = '3';" to retrieve user ID's of all the members of group 3.

My problem is that I currently have a list of all users IDs, which I got from a form, using the statements :

```
int i = 0;
String[] names = { Request.Form["usernames"]Split(' ') }; //retrieving names from form
List<int> user_ids = new List<int>();
foreach(string name in names){ 
    int user_id = db.QueryValue("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = name");
    user_ids.Add(user_id); //now I have a list of all user_ids
}
```

I now wish to insert this data into the groups table, where all of the user_id values in the list will have the same group_ID. How can I do this?

```
//create a group from users
"INSERT INTO group (group_id, user_id) VALUES(?,?);
```

Comment: Is the `group` table structured (first that's a potentially troublesome name, you could run into keyword issues) such that it has no primary key?

Comment: Do you need to worry about merging lists and avoiding duplicate entries?  Are you using SQL Server 2008 (allows merge statement)?

Comment: Yes, there is no primary key. I am using the SQL Server bundled with WebMatrix, I believe its SQL Server Compact Edition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are talking about is a many-many relationship.  You already have a users table:

```
**users**
userid
username
```

You need an additional table in the middle.  The group table will just have something like:

```
**group***
groupid
groupName
```

You would then have a table in the middle.  This table would look something like this:

```
**user_groups**
userid
groupid
```

You could still use your code to insert a user,

```
int i = 0;
String[] names = { Request.Form["usernames"]Split(' ') }; //retrieving names from form
List<int> user_ids = new List<int>();
foreach(string name in names){ 
    int user_id = db.QueryValue("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = name");
    user_ids.Add(user_id); //now I have a list of all user_ids
}
```

After this, you would insert a group:

```
insert into group(groupName) values("Sample Group")
```

Then you could retrieve the group id and use that to insert into user_groups

```
select groupid from group where groupname="Sample Group"

insert into user_groups(userid,groupid) values(...
```

Also, the table structure should include primary keys and foreign keys (much like @sixlettervariables' answer)

Comment: thank you very much for this response. I am confused however, how this would allow me to use the code I have above? Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make this cleaner, you'll probably want to refactor your database setup slightly such that a third table relates users to groups:

```
users      (user_id pk, ...)
groups     (group_id pk, ...)
membership (user_id fk, group_id fk) unique(user_id, group_id)
```

[image: Visualization of User-Group-Membership relations]

When you needed to make a new group you simply insert into the `groups` table, obtain the `group_id`, and use that to populate the `membership` table for each of the users in that group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the select as the input to the insert

```
INSERT INTO group (group_id, user_id)
SELECT 1, user_id FROM users WHERE username in ("name1", name2")
```

You can join the names array back together with some commas.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate the user_ids list and do a separate insert statement for each user id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know 3, you can do this without pulling the user ids into a local list and then inserting them individually (put in quotes specifically because the OP has their query in a similar string):

```
"INSERT dbo.group(group_id, user_id) 
   SELECT 3, user_id 
   FROM dbo.users 
   WHERE username = name;"
```

If you don't already know the group id, then please explain how you determined the group id should be 3.

**EDIT** based on further info.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Groups
(
  GroupID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
  GroupName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.GroupUsers
(
  GroupID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY
    REFERENCES dbo.Groups(GroupID),
  UserID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY
    REFERENCES dbo.Users(UserID),
  PRIMARY KEY(GroupID, UserID)
);
```

Now when you want to create a new group and add users to it:

```
DECLARE @GroupID INT;
INSERT dbo.Groups(GroupName) SELECT N'whatever (unique)';
SELECT @GroupID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Now you can loop through each user id:

```
INSERT dbo.GroupUsers(GroupID, UserID) SELECT @GroupID, <userid>;
```

Comment: 3 is just a unique group ID for a list of users; I wanted it to be AUTO_INCREMENTED for each group, if you get my meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all of the User ID's from one table into another using a sub-select and union statement as follows:

```
INSERT INTO group_table_name([user_id]) SELECT [user_id] FROM table_name
UNION ALL
```

By the way, you might want to change that table name since "group" is a keyword in SQL Server. Just a tip.

Answer (score 0):

> Insert Into GroupTable (GroupId, UserID) Select GroupID, USerID from UserTable group by GroupID, UserID)

This would work :)